# Fade out background of a popup

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

i made a site with Wordpress and use the plugin Hustle to create popups. I want the grey background (mask) to fade out when the popup closes.

This is my code which makes the background mask to fade in:

```
.wph-modal-mask.wpmudev-modal-mask  {
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
-moz-animation: fadein 2s;
animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

If you go on my site
http://michael-helmbrecht.de/main/
you can see the popup if you click at the first image in the portfolio.

Comment: It works as you're describing you expect. What is your question?

Comment: I want that the background fades out when the popup closes.

Comment: Which it does. So?

Answer (score 0):

Heloo Michael

you can setup an animation to **fadeout** the background just as you did for fadein, the only difference here is that you interchange the opacity values for from and to
like below

```
@keyframes fadeout {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to   { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to   { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

after specifying the keyframe you can apply it on a class that will be applied on the html element you want to fade out like this

```
.wph-modal-mask.fadeout-modal-mask  {
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadeout 2s;
   animation: fadeout 2s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do i need JS to trigger the fade-out? Because the animation: fadeout 2s will be executed when .wph-modal-mask.fadeout-modal-mask loads right?

Comment: you will need JS to add the class to the html. Adding the class to the class to the html element will trigger the animation. You can use the jQuery method $(".wph-modal-mask").addClass("fadeout-modal-mask") whiles you remove the fadein class $(".wph-modal-mask").removeClass("wpmudev-modal-mask")